# In-file data copy using DMA

Tags: c#, file, dma

I need to move some data from one area of a file to another.  Currently, I am reading the bytes and writing them back out.  But I'm wondering if doing a DMA transfer would be faster, if it is possible.  I'm in C#, but unsafe and p/invoke functions are acceptable.

Comment: Does memcpy automatically do a DMA transfer if it is able?  If so, maybe I can use memory-mapped files and call memcpy (or memmove).

Comment: Or am I likely already doing DMA transfers and I just don't know it?  Even if this is the case, I must be doing two transfers instead of one -- to read the data and then write it.  Is there any way to make it one transfer?

Answer (score 4):

You are, as far as I can tell, *not* doing DMA 'by accident' by using the usual file streams to copy from one file to another. DMA is in use in the background in some places (for instance to transfer from disk to RAM by using FileStreams), but it cannot handle direct file-to-file stream copy in C#.

DMA itself is pretty complex and native to low level languages. I'm referring to [this document](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/pdf/howto_dma.pdf). All code examples are in C and asm, so its not directly applicable to C#.

> The DMA is another chip on your motherboard (usually is an Intel 8237 
>   chip) that allows you (the programmer) to offload data transfers 
>   between I/O boards. DMA actually stands for 'Direct Memory Access'. An
>   example of DMA usage would be the Sound Blaster's ability to play
>   samples in the background. The CPU sets up the sound card and the DMA.
>   When the DMA is told to 'go', it simply shovels the data from RAM to
>   the card. Since this is done off-CPU, the CPU can do other things
>   while the data is being transferred.

An alternative could be to let the OS handle the transfer: Simply use File.Copy.